# Plantronics Blackwire C220M microphone is not working

Tags: 12.10, usb, updates, headset

Using a full updated Ubuntu 12.10, my USB Plantronics Blackwire C220M headset's mic isn't working.

I've plugged it in and the headphones started to work immediately but mic wasn't detected. Reboot solved that and the mic appeared in the Input devices, but when I try to select it the audio setting menu just crashes.

Ubuntu asked 2 times to send a report after that's happening and now the audio setting window just silently closes after I try to select the headset's mic. Changing USB port don't help.

Comment: Did you try upgrading to 13.04 and then trying the same?

Comment: @stingus is this question still valid?